# Многостраничная GWT форма

Tags: gwt, java, веб-программирование

Как в GWT/SmartGWT можно сделать многостраничную форму, как например в обычных Windows'овских программах установки: левая половина статична, в правой половине меняются разные панели при нажатии кнопок "Далее", "Назад"?
Интересует правая часть с множеством панелей, которые меняются только програмно.
Заголовков панелей, как например на TabPanel или StackPanel, не должно быть видно.

Comment: <a href="http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckPanel.html">DeckPanel</a> то, что я искал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите

http://uptick.com.au/content/build-user-interface

Там вообще хороший (правда большой) пример приложения.

Начинаете с Getting started with smartGWT (http://uptick.com.au/content/getting-started-smartgwt)
и идете по What's Next в конце каждой страницы.

Comment: Приложение действительно большое, пример хороший. Мы работаем на Eclipse и форму строим при прмощи GWT Designer, не подскажете какие компоненты использовать?

Comment: Не, я Designer не пробовал. Все ручками.

Comment: Designer не используете потому, что есть отрицательные стороны использования?

Comment: Я просто не люблю изучать новые и потом еще более новые инструменты.